# Failed to connect mongodb from nodejs using mongodbDriver on windows server 2003

Tags: node.js, mongodb, windows-server-2003

I check the  MongoDB service is in running and I can connect MongoDB unsing /bin/mongo.exe **BUT** I cannot connect to MongoDB server using nodejs driver.

My codes are working on Windows 10. The error messages are below.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\src\server>node server.js
Listening on port 80

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\src\server\node_modules\mongodb\
lib\mongo_client.js:225
          throw err
          ^
 MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\src\ser
ver\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:313:
35)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at emit (events.js:169:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\src\ser
ver\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:260:12
)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\src\s
erver\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.j
s:162:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lower version of mongodb driver.
In this case, I use 1.4.